How to find the number of all closed regions?
We need to write a program in python according to the following logic:
For example we have line coordinate data, where each tuple is a line of two points.
coordinates = [(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0), (50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0), (50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0), (0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0)].

The task is to identify all line connections that form a closed region and output the number of these regions. In this example, there is a square. So the output should be 1
Other input data about coordinates:
coordinates = [(0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0), (50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0), (50.0, 50.0, 0.0, 50.0), (0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 0.0)]

In this case, there is a square and a line dividing it in half. The program must determine that in this case this line divides our square in half and therefore now we have 3 closed figures.
So it should output - 2. Because a closed area, within which there are still closed areas, is no longer counted.
That is, the point is to output the number of all closed objects separately
Here's a code that can only find one closed region:
def find_connected_lines(coordinates):
    connected_lines = []

    lines_dict = {}
    for line in coordinates:
        for i in range(0, len(line), 2):
            point = (line[i], line[i + 1])
            if point not in lines_dict:
                lines_dict[point] = []
            lines_dict[point].append(line)

    def dfs(point):
        if point not in visited:
            visited.add(point)
            for line in lines_dict[point]:
                for i in range(0, len(line), 2):
                    next_point = (line[i], line[i + 1])
                    if next_point != point:
                        dfs(next_point)

    for point in lines_dict:
        if len(lines_dict[point]) == 2:
            connected_lines.append(lines_dict[point][0])
            visited = set()
            dfs(point)

    return connected_lines


def count_closed_areas(coordinates):
    connected_lines = find_connected_lines(coordinates)
    count = 0
    while connected_lines:
        line = connected_lines.pop()
        count += 1
        for other_line in list(connected_lines):
            if set(line).intersection(set(other_line)):
                connected_lines.remove(other_line)
    return count


coordinates1 = [(0.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 50.0, 50.0, 50.0), (0.0, 0.0, 50.0, 0.0), (50.0, 0.0, 50.0, 50.0)]
print("Number of enclosed areas:", count_closed_areas(coordinates1))


I'm always curious, what makes some people write "we" when talking about themselves.

Count the cycles in a graph?

@lastchance, Maybe. I tried all the looping methods from networkx, but none of them helped. need to find all closed areas

@MarcinOrlowski, the 'we' in the question clearly refers to 'me and other students'. As they got the task and not him alone. So he is not talking about himself..

Can the fifth line also be ( 0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 25.0)? And maybe a sixth line (25.0, 0.0, 25.0, 50.0)? If so, would the answer for that latter input be 9?

@trincot, ideally, with this arrangement of lines we should get 6 closed areas. The fact is that if there is a closed area, inside of which there are still closed areas, then we no longer count this area.
